# R ifelse - unexpected change in vector order

Tags: r

I am getting an unexpected result after running:

```
 test = c(rep(FALSE, 2), rep(TRUE, 6))
 ifelse(test, c(1:8)[test], 1)
[1] 1 1 5 6 7 8 3 4
```

I would have expected `1 1 3 4 5 6 7 8` but the indexes of `yes` in `ifelse(test, yes, no)` are turned. Maybe I need more coffee but I would appreciate if anyone could explain the logic behind this result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lengths of the vectors in `ifelse` should be the same.  In the OP's code, the second argument is again subsetted while the third argument 1 gets recycled (fine though)

```
ifelse(test, 1:8, 1)
#[1] 1 1 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

---

It is explained in the documentation of `?ifelse`

> If yes or no are too short, their elements are recycled. yes will be
>   evaluated if and only if any element of test is true, and analogously
>   for no.

Here, the 'yes', 'no' denotes to the general usage arguments in `ifelse`

> ifelse(test, yes, no)