# R How to select a value in a dataframe by selecting specific row and column

Tags: r

My dataframe looks like this:

```
      var1      var2    var3
1     2         5       "other"
2     25        3       "sample"
3     4         5       "baseline_other"
4     60        5       "baseline_sample"
5     40        5       "other"
6     60        5       "other"
7     25        3       "sample"
8     6         8       "other"
9     60        7       "other"
10    4         3       "other"
```

I want to add a new column in which I do a calculation that uses the value of `df$var1` of row `df$var3==baseline_other` in case the `df$var3 == "other"`.

And if `df$var3 == "sample"` it should use the value of `df$var1` of row `df$var3==baseline_sample`. (I hope i'm making myself clear). So i would like to give `x_other`   the value of `df$var1` in row `baseline_other`. (And the same for `x_sample` using `baseline_sample`).

I tried `x_other <- df[df$var3=="baseline_other",df$var1]` but i get an error saying `undefined columns selected`.

When I could make this work I would further like to add a column with a calculation (as I mentioned above) that would then look like this:

```
df$new <- ifelse(df$var3=="other", (abs(df$var1-x_other)/x_other), NA)
```

and repeat this for "sample" so:

```
df$new <- ifelse(df$var3=="sample", (abs(df$var1-x_sample)/x_sample), NA)
```

I hope I made myself clear enough. But my problem is to actually select a certain value in my dataframe by row name and column and then use that value in a calculation.

My new df should look like this:

```
      var1      var2    var3                 var4
1     2         5       "other"              0.5
2     25        3       "sample"             0.6
3     4         5       "baseline_other"     NA
4     60        5       "baseline_sample"    NA
5     40        5       "other"              9
6     60        5       "other"              14
7     25        3       "sample"             0.6
8     6         8       "other"              0.5
9     60        7       "other"              14
10    4         3       "sample"             0.9
```

Comment: why the 'var1' is changed in the input and expected?

Comment: In `df[df$var3=="baseline_other",df$var1]`, you are doing an inappropriate column subscript. That should simply be `df[df$var3=="baseline_other", "var1"]`

Comment: @akrun sorry my mistake, edited it!

Comment: I thought a [nested ifelse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012222/nested-ifelse-statement) statement would do the trick, like this: `df$calc <- ifelse(df$var3 == "other", 
                  abs(((df$var1[df$var3 == "other"])-(df$var1[df$var3 == "baseline_other"])))/(df$var1[df$var3 == "baseline_other"]),
                  ifelse(df$var3 == "sample", 
                  abs(((df$var1[df$var3 == "sample"])-(df$var1[df$var3 == "baseline_sample"])))/(df$var1[df$var3 == "baseline_sample"]),
                  NA))`. But the order of "other" values is off, while outside of ifelse it's fine.

Comment: Perhaps that order change mentioned in my first comment has to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699799/r-ifelse-unexpected-change-in-vector-order), but I don't understand how that applies here and how to fix it.